# Trigger multi Row en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, insert

Intento hacer un trigger para cuando inserto en una tabla por ejemplo: **tabla usuarios** y que tiene 3 campos **ID**, **nombres**, **apellidos**; entonces pienso llenar la tabla de **auditoría_usuarios** que tiene los siguientes campos: **ID,id_usuario,nombres_old,apellidos_old,nombres_new,apellidos_new,fecha_modificacion**; entonces tengo el siguiente triggers:

```
create trigger au_usuario_i on usuarios after insert as begin insert into auditoría_usuarios Values(ID.inserted,'','',nombres.inserted,apellidos.inserted.getdate()) End.
```

Mi problema viene cuando intento insertar varios datos en usuarios ejemplo:

```
insert into usuarios values('pepito','perez'),('pepita','mendez'),('maria','la del barrio');
```

Solo se llena el primero usuario en la auditoria_usuario, alguien sabe que tengo que hacer para que tome todos los usuarios insertados en vez de solo el primero. Gracias (y)

Comment: Desgraciadamente  no tengo t-sql instalado, por lo que no voy a darte un codigo sin probar. Pero quizas te sirva esta información : https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 , Habla de la clausula OUTPUT, puedes hacer un SELECT de la tabla INSERTED , con la clausula output recoger los datos que haya en esta tabla , donde se encuentran los datos de todos los valores del INSERT y a contuniación actualizar la tabla "auditoria_usuarios". Siento no poder ayudarte más

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualmente las pseudo tablas `inserted` y `deleted` son efectivamente tablas, por lo que si quieres insertar el conjunto de los datos de las mismas puedes usar las consultas de actualización, es decir `insert into tabla (...) select ... from ...`. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
create trigger au_usuario_i on usuarios after insert as 
begin 

    insert into auditoría_usuarios (id_usuario, nombres_old, apellidos_old, nombres_new, 
                                    apellidos_new, fecha_modificacion)
    select i.id, 
           '', 
           '', 
           i.nombres, 
           i.apellidos, 
           getdate()
           from inserted i

End
```

Comentarios:

- No es buena práctica hacer un `insert` sin indicar las columnas, cuando modificas las estructura de la tabla, la sentencia dejará de funcionar.
- Respeté tu idea de completar las columnas sin datos con blancos `''`, pero tengo que sugerirte que uses directamente `NULL`, los blancos son ambiguos por que cuando el usuario explicitamente ingreso un blanco

Comment: Sugeriría incluso ir más allá y utilizar la tabla deleted para crear un trigger que sirva también para updates y deletes.